# Is there non-critical alert reporting functionality in NewRelic?

Tags: newrelic

There are a number of third-party services that our application communicates with. It is very often that we encounter some networking and other problems with these services so we want to be aware of these problems.

Ideally we want to set up some NewRelic Ruby gem code within every critical piece of our application that would notify us when these errors happen. It would be especially helpful if we were able to receive email notifications (some service was down, some service did return error because we sent it some invalid data etc).

For Android applications we use Crashlytics as crash-reporting tool and it has support for non-fatal exceptions: [Logging caught exceptions](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions). We want exactly the same functionality for our application and it would be great if we could achieve this using NewRelic.

I would highly appreciate any insight on whether this feature exists within NewRelic feature set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic currently does not offer a way to alert on non-critical problems or individual errors.  We alert on trends such as errors over a period of time via error rate.  Our Agents (Ruby, .Net, Java, etc) capture errors and you can see them on the [errors dashboard](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/events/errors-dashboard) for your application.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for response. This feature could be exteremely useful if NewRelic had it. Is there any chance that it could be added to NewRelic set of features? Thanks.